# output of negative integer to %u format specifier

Tags: c, format-specifiers

Consider the following code

```
char c=125;
c+=10;
printf("%d",c); //outputs  -121 which is understood.
printf("%u",c); // outputs 4294967175.
printf("%u",-121); // outputs 4294967175
```

%d accepts negative numbers therefore output is -121 in first case.
output in case 2 and case 3 is 4294967175. I don't understand why?

Comment: The machine does know know there is a negative value, just a binary value. The `%u` tell the code to interpret that binary value as *unsigned*.

Comment: In the first two cases, `c` is promoted to `int`.

Comment: The answer depends on whether `char` is signed or unsigned in your compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Do

> 2<sup>32</sup>  -  121 = 4294967175

`printf` interprets data you provide thanks to the `%` values

- `%d` signed integer, value from -2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup>-1
- `%u` unsigned integer, value from 0 to 2<sup>32</sup>-1

In binary, both integer values (-121 and 4294967175) are (of course) identical:

```
`0xFFFFFF87`
```

See [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: It should be mentioned that the behavior in this situation is not defined by the C standard, and the result observed occurred only because of how this particular implementation behaved in this particular situation. It is not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

printf uses something called **variadic arguments**. If you make a brief research about them you'll find out that the function that uses them does not know the *type* of the input you're passing to it. Therefore there must be a way to tell the function how it must interpret the input, and you're doing it with the format specifiers.

In your particular case, c is a 8-bit signed integer. Therefore, if you set it to the literal `-121` inside it, it will memorize: `10000111`. Then, by the **integer promotion** mechanism you have it converted to an int: `11111111111111111111111110000111`.

With "%d" you tell printf to interpret `11111111111111111111111110000111` as a signed integer, therefore you have -121 as output. However, with "%u" you're telling printf that `11111111111111111111111110000111` is an ***unsigned*** integer, therefore it will output `4294967175`.

EDIT: As stated in the comments, actually the behaviour is undefined in C. That's because you have more than one way to encode negative numbers (sign and modulo, One's complement, ...) and sone other aspects (such as endianness, if I'm not wrong, influences this result). So the result is said to be **implementation defined**. Therefore you may get a different output rather than `4294967175`. But the main concepts I explained for different interpretation of the same string of bits and the lossness of the type of data in variadic arguments still hold.

Try to convert the number into base 10, first as a pure binary number, then knowing that it's memorized in 32-bit Two's complement... you get two different results. But if I do not tell you *which* intepretation you need to use, that binary string can represent everything (a 4-char ASCII string, a number, a small 8-bit 2x2 image, your safe combination, ...).

EDIT: you can think of "%<format_string>" as a sort of "extension" for that string of bits. You know, when you create a file, you usually give it an extension, which is actually *a part of the filename*, to remember in which format/encoding that file has been stored. Let's suppose you have your favorite song saved as `song.ogg` file on your PC. If you rename the file in `song.txt`, `song.odt`, `song.pdf`, `song`, `song.akwardextension`, that **does not change the content of the file**. But if you try to open it with the program usually associated to .txt or .whatever, it reads the bytes in the file, but when it tries to interpret sequences of bytes it may fail (that's why if you open `song.ogg` with Emacs or VIm or whatever text editor you get sonething that looks like garbage information, if you open it with, for instance, GIMP, GIMP cannot read it, and if you open it with VLC you listen to your favorite song). The extension is just a reminder for you: it reminds you how to interpret that sequence of bits. As printf has no knowledge for that interpretation, you need to provide it one, and if you tell printf that a signed integer is acutally unsigned, well, it's like opening song.ogg with Emacs...

Comment: It should be mentioned that the behavior in this situation is not defined by the C standard, and the result observed occurred only because of how this particular implementation behaved in this particular situation. It is not reliable.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, Thanks for make me noticing the incompleteness of my answer. I updated it. Anyway, the other arguments (lossness of type in variadic arguments and ambiguous interpretation of the same piece of data) still hold. Even though I could argue that "In your particular case" means that I referred to his specific C implementation...

Answer (score 1):

`printf` is a function with variadic arguments. In such case a "default argument promotions" are applied on arguments before the function is called. In your case, `c` is first converted from `char` to `int` and then sent to `printf`. The conversion does not depend on the corresponding '%' specifier of the format. The value of this `int` parameter can be interpreted as 4294967175 or -121 depending on signedness. The corresponding parts in the C standard are:

> 6.5.2.2 Function call
>
> 6 - ... If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a
>   prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that
>   have type float are promoted to double. These are called the default argument
>   promotions.
>
> 7- If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does include a prototype,
>   the arguments are implicitly converted, as if by assignment, to the types of the
>   corresponding parameters, taking the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version
>   of its declared type. The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes
>   argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. The default argument
>   promotions are performed on trailing arguments.

Comment: It should be mentioned that the behavior in this situation is not defined by the C standard, and the result observed occurred only because of how this particular implementation behaved in this particular situation. It is not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

If `char` is signed in your compiler (which is the most likely case) and is 8 bits wide (extremely likely,) then `c+=10` will overflow it. Overflow of a signed integer results in undefined behavior. This means you can't reason about the results you're getting.

If `char` is unsigned (not very likely on most PC platforms), then see the other answers.

Comment: The fact that the C standard does not define integer overflow means you cannot reason about it **using the C standard alone**. It does not mean you cannot reason about it at all. Even when you reach the limits of the C standard, everything else in the world still works by its own rules—the rules of physics still apply, the rules of logic still apply, computers still work as built, and software still executes according to the machine it is on. One can reason about why -121 produces “ 4294967175” even while recognizing it is not guaranteed by the C standard.

Comment: The other answers so far are also defective in that they fail to explain this behavior is not defined by the C standard. But a good answer both explains that this behavior is not defined by the C standard and explains why we saw the result we did.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm not sure where the laws of physics come in. If there's undefined behavior, the compiler can just assume things that aren't true. Undefined behavior gives the compiler a license to generate code or delete code in ways that prevent you from reasoning about the code.

Comment: Yes, the compiler is **allowed** to do anything by the C standard. But it did not just “do anything” here. “4294967175” was not printed as the result of random processes. There are reasons it was printed, and we know those reasons. The statement that we cannot reason about the results is false.