# Why unsigned int stills signed?

Tags: c

I create an unsigned int and unsigned char. Then I assign the -10 value, and the char remains unsigned and gives me a value of 246, but the unsigned int takes the -10 value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{


unsigned char a;
unsigned int b;
a=-10; 
b=-10;
printf("%d\t%d\n", a,b);

}
```

Compiling and executing I have this:

```
246     -10
```

I have no idea why the unsigned int stills signed, and why the char is unsigned.

Reading the book "The C programming language 2nd edition" I can see char can be unsigned by default depending on the machine.

(I'm running `NetBSD` as a operating system.)

Why the int is signed while I'm declaring as unsigned int, and why the char is taking the value 246?

Is this a compiler or system operating "feature" ?

Comment: Because `%d` is for signed integers.

Comment: `%d` tells the function to “interpret” that argument as a signed integer, regardless of its declaration (as long as it passes the compiler's semantic check)

Comment: why the char can't get the -10 value then?

Comment: It can get the -10 value if I create a normal char

Comment: It illegal to use `%d` to `printf` an `unsigned int` value that is greater than `INT_MAX`. The behavior is undefined, the output is nonsensical. There's no point in askking "why" questions about undefined behavior.

Comment: @AnT - it is not "illegal" to use `%d` format for an `unsigned int`.   It gives undefined behaviour.   There's a difference.

Comment: @Peter: It depends on what meaning you assign to "illegal". It is not a strictly defined term.

Comment: so many duplicates and related questions here https://stackoverflow.com/q/41399092/995714 https://stackoverflow.com/q/47599120/995714 https://stackoverflow.com/q/47739874/995714 https://stackoverflow.com/q/32344810/995714...

Comment: @AnT - English dictionary definitions of illegal amount to "forbidden by law, statute, regulation or official rules".     The meaning of "undefined" in the C standard (essentially "this standard does not constrain what happens") has nothing in common with this.

Comment: @Peter: "English dictionary" has very little to do with this. The language specification explicitly permits compilers to refuse to compile code that contains undefined behavior. This means that in general case this might be as "illegal" as regular syntax errors. Or it might not be...

Comment: @AnT - the language specification also allows an implementation to NOT diagnose undefined behaviour.   That's the point.

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc sorry, I saw no questions like this one when I was looking for. Just questions about casting signed to unsigned and something like this

Comment: What makes you think assigning a negative value to an unsigned variable makes any sense?

Comment: The result made me think that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is undefined behavior when you pass unsigned integers to `%d`. [Wrong format specifier is UB.](/a/16864590/5958455)

If you assign a negative value to an unsigned variable, it's fine and the value will be taken modulo `UINT_MAX + 1` (or `UCHAR_MAX + 1`), so  `(-10) % (UCHAR_MAX + 1)` = 256 - 10 = 246, and `b` is 4294967296 - 10 = 4294967286. Unsigned integral overflow is required to wrap-around.

When `printf` is interpreting these numbers, it finds 246 is suitable for `%d`, the format specifier for `signed int`, and 4294967286 is reinterpreted as -10. That's all.

Comment: So the int really is not unsigned, I was thinking it was signed even I was declaring as unsigned. Thanks to all

Comment: @VMS It *is* unsigned indeed. It is re-interpreted as signed when printing.

Comment: lol sorry, I wanted to say "the int really is unsigned"

Comment: "...4294967286 is converted to -10". That's misleading. Standard `printf` is not capable of performing *conversions*, since it has no knowledge of the source type. The best it can do is *reinterpretation*. But formally the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @AnT Thanks for pointing out. Sorry for my bad English :(

Comment: Note: passing char to %d is well-defined on most systems because of integer promotions (the exception would be a system where char was both unsigned and the same size as int)..

Answer (score 1):

When you assign `-10` to an `unsigned char` variable, the value is reduced modulo `UCHAR_MAX + 1`, which results in `246` on your platform. Printing an `unsigned char` value using format `%d` is fine on most platforms. The value gets implicitly converted to `int`, which is the correct type for `%d` format. So, you see that `246` as you should.

When you assign `-10` to an `unsigned int` variable, the value is reduced modulo `UINT_MAX + 1`, which results in some large value (depends on the range of `unsigned int` on your platform). Printing such large `unsigned int` value (greater than `INT_MAX`) using format `%d` leads to *undefined behavior*. The output is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

`%d` is the specifier used to print `signed int`, so it is not strange. Use `%u` instead.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

And when you assign a negative value to an unsigned variable you will get overflow. That's why you get strange values.

`printf("%d", a)` means that will take the content of variable `a` and *interpret* it as a signed int.

Oh, and btw. You are causing *undefined behavior* which implies that there's really no reason to ask why something happens. Undefined behavior will always be undefined. Avoid it at all costs. Note that the only thing that is undefined is the printf statement. Assigning a value that's out of range to an unsigned variable is a defined behavior. However, the opposite is not true. `int a = UINT_MAX` will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: 246     4294967286 That's what I have if I use %u instead

Comment: are they substracting 10 of their maximum possible value? Why those numbers?

Comment: @VMS - Because that's what the standard requires. Overflow of unsigned integral types uses modulo arithmetic.   So `-10` converted to an `unsigned` gives a result of `UINT_MAX + 1 - 10` where `UINT_MAX` (available in `<limits.h>`) is the maximum value an `unsigned` can represent.   A typical 32-bit `unsigned` type has `UINT_MAX` equal to `4294967295`.

Comment: @klutt That's why I'm asking, Unsigned means like you say The variable cannot handle negative numbers, but the int still handling it while the char cannot

Comment: @VMS No, the printf statement *interpret* the content in the variable as a signed int. That's a difference.

Comment: Yes, now I understand, thanks to all guys